# Make a web requsted or post, to external URL for data

Tags: office-scripts

Is it possible to make web requests to an external url to grab data or post data to?

This way you can easily get data from external API's.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the document to doing web requests in Office Scripts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs?view=word-js-preview

Comment: The document you linked is for Custom Functions, but the same principles apply—`fetch()` and `XMLHttpRequest()` will both work in Office Scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that there is JavaScript for Office Add-ins (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/?view=word-js-preview) and should be tagged #office-js.
This type of JavaScript can be used in different Office applications (web and desktop) to create add-ins that will work in both web apps and desktop applications.
This Office JavaScript API can be explored using Script Lab.

The tag #Office-Scripts reference **Office Scripts for Excel on the web** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/) which is also in preview and currently only available in Excel on the Web.
It can be enabled from the Admin portal of Microsoft365 (Formerly Office 365) under Settings/Settings and appears in Excel on the Web as a new tab called Automation.
It gives users the possibility to record macros and create scripts via the Office Scripts editor pane. Office-Scripts for Excel on the Web uses TypeScript. It is more limited in its scope than Office Add-in JavaScript.

So, to answer the question with regards to Office-Scripts for Excel on the Web, and as stated in the documentation, it is currently not possible to reference external API.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/add-ins-differences